# Entity Framework Slow Filtering Associated Entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ria

The EntityFramework seems very slow when populating a filtered child EntityCollection on an Entity -

We're running a RIA/WCF Web App using database first Entity Framework written in C# with a Silverlight client. We have a collection of about 70,000 'Eval' entities and a similar number of 'InCo' entities. Each Eval has a child collection of InCo entities containing at most 2. The relationship is one to many so an Eval can have multiple InCos but an InCo is tied to a single Eval. After loading the entity collections from the database I'm looping through the Evals like so -

```
    foreach(Eval eval in Evals)
        if (eval.InCos.Count > 0)
            // Do something
```

This is taking a long time (minutes). Stepping through the code I found there's a generated function **FilterInCos** on the Eval entity to determine whether an InCo has an association with it (in the generated .Web.g.cs file) and this is passed to the constructor of the Eval's InCos EntityCollection and invoked to populate that collection when one of its properties is referenced for the first time

```
    private bool FilterInCos(InCo entity)
    {
        return (entity.EvalID == this.EvalID);
    }
```

From what I can see the FilterInCos() function is called for each InCo in the InCos collection for each Eval - that's 70,000 calls for each of the 70,000 Evals resulting in around 5 billion iterations to loop through the Evals and query the InCos collection on each one. As the Eval:InCo database relationship is 1:* it should be possible to loop through the InCo objects, retrieve the Eval with a matching EvalID and add the InCo to that Eval's InCos collection - 70,000 iterations. However there doesn't seem to be a way to circumvent the generated logic as I see it. Neither can we just assign an EntityCollection to the InCos property of the Eval as it is read only.

Here's the relevant database relationship from the EF edmx file -

```
    <Association Name="FK_InCo_Eval">
      <End Role="Eval" Type="AspireEntityModel.Store.Eval" Multiplicity="1">
        <OnDelete Action="Cascade" />
      </End>
      <End Role="InCo" Type="AspireEntityModel.Store.InCo" Multiplicity="*" />
      <ReferentialConstraint>
        <Principal Role="Eval">
          <PropertyRef Name="EvalID" />
        </Principal>
        <Dependent Role="InCo">
          <PropertyRef Name="EvalID" />
        </Dependent>
      </ReferentialConstraint>
    </Association>
```

Here's the InCos property on the Eval client-side entity (from the generated .Web.g.cs) with the generated constructor

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the collection of associated <see cref="InCo"/> entity instances.
    /// </summary>
    [Association("Eval_InCo", "EvalID", "EvalID")]
    [XmlIgnore()]
    public EntityCollection<InCo> InCos
    {
        get
        {
            if ((this._InCos == null))
            {
                this._InCos = new EntityCollection<InCo>(this, "InCos", this.FilterInCos, this.AttachInCos, this.DetachInCos);
            }
            return this._InCos;
        }
    }
```

Has anyone found similar behaviour on a database-first EF application and can suggest a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I found a very similar problem once a production databases started to get million's of records. To cut a long story short:-

First) unless I am composing queries I always use .ToList() to force a single round trip to the database prior to any foreach() loop.

Second) I never use navigation properties within a loop if I can collect the data in the first query.

Thirdly) Rather than getting very wide results I attempt to get two separate lists (using .ToList ) one of Eval and one of InCos and then do a Linq.FirstOrDefault() to join them in memory, however I have to consider memory overhead and data transfer time.

in your case I would modify the select used to gather Evals something like:-

```
var Evals = from Ev in db.Evals
            select new {
                Ev,
                Cnt = Ev.Incos.Count()
                }

foreach(var Eval in Evals)
if (Eval.Cnt > 0)
    .......

and access the Eval as Eval.Ev
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you can make the query more efficient by filtering it in the query itself:

```
foreach(Eval eval in Evals.Where(e => e.InCos.Any())
```

This moves all filtering to the server, so no additional expensive queries for each `Eval` record are necessary.

And if you need to do something with the `InCos` you should eagerly load them:

```
foreach(Eval eval in Evals.Expand("InCos").Where(e => e.InCos.Any())
```